# ArgumentError: x and back-reference y are both of the same direction <RelationshipDirection.ONETOMANY: 1>. Where is the issue?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, both are derived from abstract "Chats" table, Merchant and Trader. I need to establish one-to-many relationship, so that Trader could have multiple merchants linked. But when I try, I get ArgumentError.

Here are DDL classes for tables, both is SQLAlchemy-based

```
class Merchant(Chat):
    __tablename__ = "merchant"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "calc_bot"}
    chat_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("calc_bot.chat.chat_id"), primary_key=True)
    trader_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column( Integer(),ForeignKey("calc_bot.trader.t_id"))
    linked_trader: Mapped[Optional["Trader"]] = relationship("Trader", back_populates="merchants", foreign_keys="calc_bot.trader.c.t_id", primaryjoin="calc_bot.trader.c.t_id == calc_bot.merchant.c.trader_id")
    updated_on: Mapped[datetime]  = mapped_column(default=datetime.now())
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "merchant",
        "inherits": Chat
    }
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"Merchant(id={self.chat_id!r}, chat_name={self.chat_name!r})"


class Trader(Chat):
    __tablename__ = "trader"
    __table_args__ = {"schema": "calc_bot"}
    t_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column( Integer(), index=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    chat_id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(ForeignKey("calc_bot.chat.chat_id"), unique=True)
    deposit: Mapped[int]
    trader_rate: Mapped[float]
    merchants: Mapped[List["Merchant"]] = relationship("Merchant", back_populates="linked_trader", foreign_keys="calc_bot.merchant.c.trader_id")
    updated_on: Mapped[datetime]  = mapped_column(default=datetime.now())
    __mapper_args__ = {
        "polymorphic_identity": "trader",
        "inherits": Chat
    }
```

I tried multiple combinations of key, primary_key and foreign_key variants, but nothing helped